# How do I do this SQL query

Tags: sql, database, schema

The following are the tables I am working with:

Movie(mID, title, year, director)

Reviewer(rID, name)

Rating(rID, mID, stars, ratingDate)

which statement would I use to display all movies that have no ratings. I am new to the SQL language and can't quite see how this can be done. From what I have been told this is a relatively simple query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM Movie WHERE Movie.mid NOT IN (SELECT mID FROM Rating)`

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to do this. My preference is for an Anti-Join, which is a LEFT JOIN with a where clause test for IS NULL on the right side of the join.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   Movie
   LEFT JOIN Rating
    ON moive.Mid = rating.mid
WHERE
    rating.mid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from movie where mID not in (select mId from rating)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NOT EXISTS clause. A good example for Oracle is at http://www.dba-oracle.com/sql/t_subquery_not_in_exists.htm. The syntax may vary depending on your database